# jQuery replace string of an element

Tags: jquery, replace

I'd like to replace character "@" by "(at)" within all span tags that contain @ character.
Is there anything like `$('span:contains("@")').text().replace` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippet that you have posted is one of the options. But you need to reset the text content of the element.

```
$('span:contains("@")').text(function(_, text) {
     return text.replace(/@/g, '(at)');
});
```

Here is a non-jQuery alternative:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('span'), function(span) {
    if ( span.textContent.includes('@') ) {
       span.textContent = span.textContent.replace(/@/g, '(at)');
    }
});
```

Please note that resetting `.textContent` can be destructive if the element has child elements. In that case you can reset the html content of the element (`.innerHTML`) or better, filter the text nodes of the element.